# Hybris SmartEdit - grant user edit rights just for one content page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'd like to let some of our staff edit one of the pages on our website which is build on SAP Hybris 6.7, but I can't find the way to achieve this.

For example one of the pages has Page ID *cmsitem_00016005* (see atached screenshot) and I'd like the user to be able to login to SmartEdit and then edit ONLY this page. Is this even possible?

JF

[Smartedit screenshot for cmsitem_00016005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AVCm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization working type based in hybris. You can create new page type (item.xml) then set rights for it.

Dirty solution: using validator for checking custom user rights.